# C# - Multiple Insert Into Statements - Error = ORA-00922: missing or invalid option\n

Tags: c#, oracle, insert

I am new to developing against an Oracle database with C#.  I have code that creates a lot of INSERT INTO statements, and I am trying to pass these statements through C# code to be executed on the Oracle server.

Basically I build a string that has "N" number of Insert Into statements combined together.  Then I call this code to try and execute them.  NOTE - If I copy the contents of the string out and execute it inside of SQL Developer it runs fine.  However, when it is executed through the following code I get the ORA-00922: missing or invalid option\n.

I have tried including the ";" at the end of each line, and I have tried excluding the ";" at the end of each line.

FYI -- The "replace" statements are lines of code I put in based on other post that I read to try and solve the issue.  I have no intention of leaving them in the final code if they are not needed.  So far, they have not made any difference.

My questions are as follows...
1. Do I need to include the ";" at the end of each INSERT INTO statement
2. Is there a better way to do the multiple INSERT INTO as a batch
3. What is this error telling me, like I said, if I copy the contents of what is being executed out and run it in SQL Developer it runs fine.

Also, I am doing a SET DEFINE OFF; prior to executing the code.

```
                       try
                        {
                            sHold = sBatch.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
                            sBatch = sHold;
                            sHold = sOptioins + sBatch;
                            sToExecute = sHold.Replace("\n", "");
                            sHold = sToExecute.Replace("\r", "");
                            sToExecute = sHold;
                            OracleHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(OracleConnection, CommandType.Text, sToExecute);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message.ToString());
                        }
```

Here is a sample of the SQL that I am trying to execute.  This is what gets dynamically built and passed over to Oracle.  This is also what works fine if I copy it and paste it directly in SQL Developer.

SET DEFINE OFF;  INSERT INTO PLCYFLYR.POLICY_SQL (POLICYID,USERNAME,TRAVELSECTORID,POLICYNAME,EMAILSUBJECT,EMAILBODY,ENABLED,NOTIFYTRAVELER,NOTIFYSUPERVISOR,ANDED,POLICYEMAILSENABLED,DATEINSERTED,DATEUPDATED,EXCLUDEVIPS,NOTIFYARRANGER,FROMADDRESS,POLICYINTERVALID,POLICYTYPEID,POLICYSTARTDATE,POLICYENDDATE,ENABLEDDATERANGE,POLICYOWNER,INCLUDETRAVELERTYPE,EMAILFOOTER,DATEFORMAT,EMAILBODYPLAIN,RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY,IS_RECURRING_POLICY,MESSAGE_TYPE) VALUES (6,'hoppe116',1,'Advance Purchase - less than 7 days','Advance Purchase Less Than 7 days','Dear Traveler,
Our records indicate that your upcoming trip, referenced below, was ticketed less than seven days in advance of your scheduled departure.  Our travel policy recommends that whenever possible airline tickets should be purchased at least seven days in advance of travel.
','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',to_date('6/9/2008 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('8/4/2009 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'Y','N','travelmanager@craneco.com','0','C',to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'N','hoppe116','','','DD-Mon-YYYY','','0','0','E'); INSERT INTO PLCYFLYR.POLICY_SQL (POLICYID,USERNAME,TRAVELSECTORID,POLICYNAME,EMAILSUBJECT,EMAILBODY,ENABLED,NOTIFYTRAVELER,NOTIFYSUPERVISOR,ANDED,POLICYEMAILSENABLED,DATEINSERTED,DATEUPDATED,EXCLUDEVIPS,NOTIFYARRANGER,FROMADDRESS,POLICYINTERVALID,POLICYTYPEID,POLICYSTARTDATE,POLICYENDDATE,ENABLEDDATERANGE,POLICYOWNER,INCLUDETRAVELERTYPE,EMAILFOOTER,DATEFORMAT,EMAILBODYPLAIN,RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY,IS_RECURRING_POLICY,MESSAGE_TYPE) VALUES (7,'hoppe116',1,'Advance Purchase - less than 7 days (Authorizer)','Advance Purchase Less Than 7 days','Dear Traveler,
Our records indicate that your upcoming trip, referenced below, was ticketed less than seven days in advance of your scheduled departure.  Our travel policy recommends that whenever possible airline tickets should be purchased at least seven days in advance of travel.
','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',to_date('6/9/2008 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('8/4/2009 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'Y','N','travelmanager@craneco.com','0','C',to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'N','hoppe116','','','DD-Mon-YYYY','','0','0','E'); INSERT INTO PLCYFLYR.POLICY_SQL (POLICYID,USERNAME,TRAVELSECTORID,POLICYNAME,EMAILSUBJECT,EMAILBODY,ENABLED,NOTIFYTRAVELER,NOTIFYSUPERVISOR,ANDED,POLICYEMAILSENABLED,DATEINSERTED,DATEUPDATED,EXCLUDEVIPS,NOTIFYARRANGER,FROMADDRESS,POLICYINTERVALID,POLICYTYPEID,POLICYSTARTDATE,POLICYENDDATE,ENABLEDDATERANGE,POLICYOWNER,INCLUDETRAVELERTYPE,EMAILFOOTER,DATEFORMAT,EMAILBODYPLAIN,RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY,IS_RECURRING_POLICY,MESSAGE_TYPE) VALUES (8,'holmw166',1,'Airline Ticket Exchange','Airline Ticket Exchange','Please note - You do not need to reply to this email...
Our records indicate your airfare ticket was exchanged.  The average exchanged ticket creates an additional cost of three times the price of the original ticket.  These additional fees cost Crane Co ~$540,000 annually.  Although we understand travel needs change, please ensure travel plans are firm prior to purchasing tickets.  If you have already begun your travel and need to depart at an earlier time, please call a Carlson Wagonlit agent to see if seats are available on a stand-by basis.
This message was sent due to one of the below reasons:
   1)  Traveler exchanged a ticket due to change in travel plans 
   2)  Traveler utilized an unused ticket for exchange
   3)  CWT systemically processed an unused ticket for exchange via automated process
   4)  Airline Vendor flight schedule change causing ticket to be re-issued - NO additional exchange fee 
Additional Service fees are applied whenever a ticket is exchanged and a new ticket is required to be issued.
A monthly report will be compiled to review and understand all airline ticket exchanges and will be shared with the BU CFO, SC Leader, and Travel Council.
','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',to_date('6/9/2008 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('8/9/2012 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'Y','N','travelmanager@craneco.com','0','C',to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'N','hoppe116','','','DD-Mon-YYYY','','0','0','E');

Comment: FYI -- The SQL in the above post SAMPLE is one INSERT INTO statement. I have code in place that will attempt to BATCH multiple statements, like this one, into a single call to Oracle.  I have been working on this for several days now and can not get past this.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated..  Thanks

Comment: In an attempt to try and narrow this down even more, I tried to execute the following ONLY.  This also gives me the same error.  This is just a single command without even trying to do an insert into.  SET DEFINE OFF;

Comment: FYI -- If I execute a SELECT or a DELETE it works, however, if I execute the "set define off;" it gives the error.  So, my issue may not necessarily be with my INSERT INTO as much as it is with the "Set Define Off" statement.  This statement has to be executed because, as you can see in my SQL example in my post, I have HTML characters in the insert statement such as &nbsp; and when I try to execute this without the set define off it does not like the &.

Comment: you'll want to bind an array of values using odp.net, you can't run a script as a single execute statement.  You either do 1 insert at a time in a loop, or the better way is to bind an array of values.  See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/jp/issue-archive/o59odpnet-085168.html) for an example

Comment: Thanks "tbone", I did not see your post until AFTER I posted my answer.  I will try as you indicated with the array..  Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

OK..  The issue has nothing to do with the INSERT INTO.  The issue I was facing was three fold...
1. set define off is not valid in code, and only works inside of the SQL Developer
2. after removing the set define off statement, I received errors due to the   contained inside of my SQL Statement, so I had to work around that.  For now I am replacing the   with [NBSP] and will then do an update when finished to switch that back to be a true   in the database.  I may try and work through this using the CHAR(38) in the code as I move forward with this.
3. the C# oracle command does not need or accept the ; because it will only process a single command at a time.  I was trying to BATCH several commands together (like I can easily do in SQL Server) and it will not allow for that..

Hope this helps others that are running into this...

Thanks,
Bruce